# Replace a string in all div except specific div

Tags: jquery, html

I want to replace all comma in a div '#tab-content-loader' except the connent in script  tag.

```
<div id="tab-content-loader">
   <div class='test1'>
    Hi, hello ,
   </div>
   <div class='test2'>
    Loream, ipsum
   </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
   <script>
      jQuery('#grid').css({position : 'relative' , width : 'inherit' , left:'inherit' , top:'inherit'});
   </script>
 </div>
</div>
```

I'm replacing the comma as

```
if ($("#tab-content-loader").length > 0 ) {
          $("#tab-content-loader").html( $("#tab-content-loader").html().replace(/,/g,"<span class='comma'>,</span>"));  
        }
 The above code replace all the comma even inside script.I want to exclude script tag content while replacing
```

now my output as

```
<div id="tab-content-loader">
   <div class='test1'>
    Hi<span class='comma'>,</span> hello <span class='comma'>,</span>
   </div>
   <div class='test2'>
    Loream<span class='comma'>,</span> ipsum
   </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
   <script>
      jQuery('#grid').css({position : 'relative' <span class='comma'>,</span> width : 'inherit' <span class='comma'>,</span> left:'inherit' <span class='comma'>,</span> top:'inherit'});
   </script>
</div>
</div>
```

Really I the the below one

```
<div id="tab-content-loader">
   <div class='test1'>
    Hi<span class='comma'>,</span> hello <span class='comma'>,</span>
   </div>
   <div class='test2'>
    Loream<span class='comma'>,</span> ipsum
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
   <script>
      jQuery('#grid').css({position : 'relative' , width : 'inherit' , left:'inherit' , top:'inherit'});
   </script>
 </div>
</div>
```

Tried as below but not working

```
if($('.modal-body script').length > 0){
  $(".modal-body").find('.comma').contents().unwrap();
  console.log('inside unwrap');
}
```

Comment: Is the script tag always a direct child of the `#tab-content-loader`?

Comment: yes.Its a direct child

Comment: Unfortunately, in the example code, it's a nested child, not a direct child

Comment: If there's nothing else inside `modal-body`, you could target it

Comment: Move your `<script>` tag outside the main div

Comment: my script is inside model-body div which is inside tab-content-loader

Comment: Is there no way at all to do this in the source? Changing default content via JS is never an ideal solution. In this case the logic will be very ugly (due to the nested elements) and you'll still end up with a FOUC

Comment: `<script>` tags disseminated around the DOM is a big *no-no* since they do block (pause) DOM parsing. So just do it properly and move the script tags right before the closing `body` tag.

Comment: you can also use `hasClass` to check if this class exists then not go for replacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to move the `script` tag so that it is a direct child of `body`. If for some reason this is not possible, then you can use a more advanced jQuery selector to only visit DOM elements that have no children, *and* that are not `script` elements:

```js
$("#tab-content-loader *:not(:has(> *)):not(script)").each(function () {
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(/,/g,"<span class='comma'>,</span>");
});

console.log($("#tab-content-loader").html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tab-content-loader">
   <div class='test1'>
    Hi, hello ,
   </div>
   <div class='test2'>
    Loream, ipsum
   </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
   <script>
      jQuery('#grid').css({position : 'relative' , width : 'inherit' , left:'inherit' , top:'inherit'});
   </script>
 </div>
</div>
```

Visiting the individual leaf-elements also has the advantage that you don't need to recreate them, meaning that any dynamic changes that were made to them (like added event listeners) will not be destroyed.

This assumes that text nodes do not have element-siblings, but always appear within their own wrapping element.

Answer (score 1):

First of, `<script>` tags should never end dispersed around the DOM, specially not at page load - since such will pause DOM parsing.
Place your script tag right before the `</body>` tag.

Otherwise... you could simply ignore the offending DIV by using `:not` selector or `.not()` method.

Use `$(this).text().replace`

```js
$("#tab-content-loader > div:not(.modal-body)").each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/,/g, '<span class="comma">,</span>'));
});
```

```css
.comma {
  background: fuchsia;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tab-content-loader">
  <div class='test1'>Hi, hello ,</div>
  <div class='test2'>Loream, ipsum</div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <script>
      jQuery('#grid').css({
        position: 'relative',
        width: 'inherit',
        left: 'inherit',
        top: 'inherit'
      });
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```